# How to make an iframe auto scroll to the bottom on reload?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

I have an iframe on my page that displays content received from a database, the content show up at the bottom of the iframe, I need to make it automatically scroll to the bottom so that messages can be read easily without scrolling manually, how do I do this and where in my page would I put the code? this is my iframe code:

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>scrollTop demo</title> <style> div.demo { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: auto; } </style> <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script> </head> <body> <div class="demo"><iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"></iframe></div> <script> $( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 300 ); </script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: This is a question about client side logic, since that is where the content is displayed. This has nothing to do with `php` or `mysql`, those tags are miss leading. You look for a javascript solution.

Comment: thank you for your help, ive fixed it now, i only added those tags because the iframe is receiving info from a PHP page referencing a MySQL database but i see how that's irrelevant to my question

Comment: i fixed the tags that is- i haven't fixed the issue yet-

Comment: Java and Javascript have nothing to do with each other. You want to tag the question "javascript".

Comment: god- im sorry, fixed it again-

Comment: any luck on answering the question? on one site it said use this line of code 
     "$("body").scrollTop(100);" but i don't know where to put it- if its even what I'm needing

Comment: The command makes sense, but just copying some line you found somewhere in the internet is not how one implements a web presence. You need to understand what you are doing, how things work and why. The question is what you load into that iframe. Sure, the response to a request to "page1.php", but what does it contain? Certainly it has to contain some javascript, either directly embedded or as a reference to a separate resource. Only you know what you are doing, so that is nothing we can answer...

Comment: In general you need to react to some client side event signaling that the content of the iframe has been fully laoded or rendered. Because only then the scrolling can get started, it makes no sense before that. Depending on what javascript framework you use (or not) the answer is different...

Comment: That line you cited is actually not vaniall javascript, it most likely relies on the jquery javascript framework. Do you use that? If so you should start with reading the documentation of that function: https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/  It comes with examples.

Comment: honestly, i dont know much about scripting languages, PHP, javascript, MySQL, databases, etc. in general, i just mainly know HTML and css, and i haven't previously used iframes before this, I'm using is now to display user input in a message box, but the messages display at the bottom of the iframe, i need to automatically see them without scrolling, i apologize if I'm not asking my question correctly, i do want to understand what I'm doing, but i can only do that once i relate it to something i understand, be it where i place the code and what the code means, some of thos terms arent familiar

Comment: The example in the documentation I referenced should provide exactly that...

Comment: i read the reference page and tons of other sources, even with specific instructions, i cant seem to find anything that works, scripting the scrolling of an iframe seems to be a tough job- I'm stumped

Comment: Then please add your attempt. The resulting html you send to the browser, not the php script. Also you should use your browsers console to debug the javascript logic you integrated (typically F12...). Any errors popping up in there?

Comment: i followed the example, except theres a problem, the div, and the iframe both have scrollbars, only one scrolls to bottom and you have to manually scroll the rest, here's my code:

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="demo"><iframe src="page1.php" width="400" height="400" scrolling="yes" font-family: "Courier New", "Lucida Console", monospace; name="myIframe"; id="myIframe"></iframe></div>
 
<script>
$( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 300 );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: please add the code to the question itself, as an "Update". There is an "edit" button below your question, use it.